# How to hyperlink Phone number in ArcGIS Online popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, hyperlink, arcgis-online-webmap

I'd like to have the phone number field in my ArcGIS Online popup to be hyperlinked so that the user can simply 'click' onto the phone number to make the appropriate call. My data contains several hundred records and so each phone number is unique.

An example of my popup looks like this:

[image]

**What I've tried**
Within the Pop-up menu, I've selected Source and tried adding an <a href ={Phone} without success.  I've done some other searches on ESRI's help page as well as StackExchange, but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a text element and use the URL link button to create a `tel:{phone number field}` link, e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback!  I've done exactly what you've provided, but testing the link both on my phone and desktop, I'm getting a duplicate browser tab instead of a 'direct dial' to the phone number.  Not sure if I'm doing something incorrect? The field name for my phone data is {Phone}, so it was easy to follow your instructions.

Comment: I'm using Chrome (on desktop) and clicking the link pops up a message asking which of my linked phones to use to make the call. I'm unable to test from a mobile device.

Comment: UPDATE - I switched Map Viewer to the Classic viewer and it works.  So, there must be a bug in Map Viewer.  Thanks for your help and answer!